# Cocoapods spec : Linking directly to closed source framework in git (not zip)

Tags: ios, xcode, git, deployment, cocoapods

Our Cocoa Touch Framework is closed source but publicly accessible. 
When creating a PodSpec, online examples show linking to a 'releases zip' in a public git repo, however, I have just tested linking directly to the .framework in the repo using git instead of http and it appears to work (see example below).

```
s.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/myaccount/MySDK.git', :tag => '0.1.0' }
s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'MySDK.framework'
```

Is there any caveats I am missing? It seems cleaner to use the git repo with tags. For clarity here is how it is advised to do it (http with zip attachment):

```
s.source = { :http => 'https://github.com/myaccount/MySDK/releases/download/0.1.0/MySDK.zip' }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's perfectly fine, I have the same structure with many of the Closed Source Frameworks which I developed.

Comment: Thanks @SachinVas So you link directly to the tagged release? Also, do you make the framework available in the same repo for Carthage without using a binary link to it?

Comment: Yes, I link directly to the tagged release. I am not sure about the Carthage, I have to explore it.